# For two data sets with different means but the same standard deviations, would the SD for the data set with a higher mean indicate lower spread?

Tags: variance, standard-deviation

I understand the actual math, but I don't understand how it makes sense.

For example, if I were working with two data sets (ex. below) and one had higher values than the other but the sizes of the standard deviation were similar would I conclude that the level of spread is more acceptable for the data set with the higher mean.

Typically, I would think no, but the coefficient of variation makes me confused.

For ex. assume for data set 1, the mean is 200 and the SD is 50. Now for data set 2 assume the mean is 500 and the SD is 50. Wouldn't the second data set result in a lower CV, meaning the data is less spread around the mean?

[image]

Comment: Your illustration, which concerns *bivariate* data, does not appear relevant to the question, which concerns *univariate* summary statistics.  Please explain the illustration.

Comment: Each point represents a mean for my data. Each error bar represents SD. For example, If I wanted to compare the CV of the two data points that equal 60 on the x axis, the CV of the orange point would be smaller, even though the error bar suggests the standard deviation is higher. I am wondering how this makes sense.

Comment: Redraw your plot on a log scale for the vertical axis.

Comment: But would't that make the trend I am trying to show impossible to see?

Comment: Not in the least!  Try it and look.